# concourse ci does not trigger on certain committed files

Tags: concourse

First, I do know that if I use `[ci skip]` in the commit message to GitHub it should not trigger based upon the commit message. However, I am only committing one file to GitHub. So instead of using this commit message, is there a way to exclude certain files? I have been researching on https://concourse-ci.org/ for this but have yet to find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `ignore_paths` in the Git resource docs:

https://github.com/concourse/git-resource#source-configuration